# Overlapping links in chrome linux

Tags: linux, google-chrome, rendering

Sometimes, at times which seem not to relate, chrome renders links overlapped on normal text. Has anyone had this experience or know how to solve the issue?

On refresh, the problem might resolve itself, or it might not.

Screenshot:

> [image: screenshot]

This was taken on the [Domai.nr api page](http://domai.nr/api/docs/json).

Comment: Please edit your question to include the version of Google Chrome you are using as well as all extensions you have installed.

Comment: My first guess would be a font or CSS issue. Looking at the page source, it is requesting one of the following fonts: `helvetica,arial,hirakakupro-w3,osaka,"ms pgothic",sans-serif`. Do you have any of these installed? What font do you have set as your default sans-serif font in Google Chrome?

Comment: I'm on Chrome 18.0.1025.151 in Linux Mint.
My default sans-serif font is Arial
I have all fonts except for _hirakakupro-w3_ and _osaka_